# How to store an object into Redis Hash using servicestack typed client?

Tags: redis, servicestack, typed

I know that I can probably get a hash

```
var myhash = mytypedclient.GetHash<MyModel>("hashkey");
```

But I get lost next. What should I do to store an instance of MyModel? I mean I do need to save the hashtable to a specified key so I can't use the high level api StoreAsHash.

If it is a list or set I can do this

```
var myset = mytypedclient.Sets<MyModel>("somesetkey");
myset.Add(instance);
```

But with Hash, eh, what should I do? I mean I need a StoreAsHash but I can set the key.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [HashTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisClientHashTests.cs) or [Typed HashTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Generic/RedisClientHashTestsBase.cs) for examples, e.g you can add an entry in the hash with:

```
mytypedclient.SetEntryInHash("hashkey", "instanceKey", instance);
```

or add it on the hash collection:

```
var myhash = mytypedclient.GetHash<MyModel>("hashkey");
myhash.Add("instanceKey", instance);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it's a little bit different than I expected. You see to store into a hash, what I've expected is that the typed client will somehow get all the properties in my object and save them one by one to the hash. For example, if my object has "first_name" and "last_name" as properties, the typed client will call SetEntryInHash(hashkey,"first_name","myname") and SetEntryInHash(hashkey,"last_name","mylast name")

Comment: In your example code, you put typedclient.SetEntryInHash("hashkey","instanceKey",Instance), my question is, what is instanceKey and instance here? I don't want to automatically translate instance into a single json-string and put it into one KEY-Value pair of a hash. Or is it what actually typedclient can do for now.

Comment: @shawhu Hash stores a dictionary of key/values. Here `instanceKey` is the KEY and `instance` is the VALUE, name borrowed from your example. The `client.StoreAsHash()` API does close to what you want.